# How to create own error red line message at design-time?

Tags: c#, exception, runtime-error, intellisense, design-time

I need to know: How to create own error red line, like "creating exceptions at run-time" editing process in IDE?

we know how to create own exception....

```
 double a = 4;
 double b = 2;
 if (b != 0)
 {
    double c = a/b;
 }
 else
 {
    throw new Exception("You can not divide by zero");
 }
```

this code will work just fine!
But.....
What if I don't run a code and I change a value of "b variable" to 0 at design-time? "I should see a error red line message. right?"
But There is no intellisense warning message!
How to create it?

```
 double a = 4;
 double b = 0;
 if (b != 0)
 {
    double c = a/b;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 }
 else
 {
    throw new Exception("You can not divide by zero");
 }
```

Comment: why you didn't use Try-catch Block ? you can Handle it with DivizionByZeroException

Comment: I want to know how does this intellisense work?  the main idea is not about this code! I need that kind of "custom intellisense runtime error messages" for other solutions!

Comment: but right now tell me how it works for this simple sample solution

Comment: it's not an intellisense, if you want to control your code in run time you should use try-catch block and if you want to check it in design time you can use 3party plugin like resharper. What do you want ? in runtime Or design time ?

Comment: I think in design time. and forget this try catch block!

Comment: Use 3rd party plugins, Like Resharper , Code Rush,..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you don't understand what Intellisense is...

IntelliSense is the stuff that pops up when you start typing a class name or a variable name or whatever. And it shows you all the options you have.

The error messages that usually pop up are none of the business of IntelliSense, they are output by the C# compiler.

In your code, there isn't error/warning message saying that `a` cannot be divided by 0 because the value of `b` might change. What if there is code on another thread changing the value of `b`? At that time, `b` is no longer 0! Also, the if clause would not even be reached!

I know you said that this question is not about *that* specific code, so let's see how you can add custom error messages.

Since error messages are generated by the C# compiler, try writing a C# compiler yourself!

No, I'm just kidding.

There are some plugins of Visual Studio that might help you with this. Maybe [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?